# Backstage Error: Invalid configuration schema in

Tags: backstage

When I try to run my backstage frontend plugin using **yarn start** facing below issue-

```
Error: Invalid configuration schema in ../../../../node_modules/@backstage/backend-common/config.d.ts, the following definitions are not supported: Partial<{[key:string]:unknown;password:string;}>
```

1. yarn - 3.2.3
2. node - 18
3. mac os Sonoma 14.3.1
4. python  3.10.12
5. backstage - 1.16.0

Have deleted nod_modules folder and did yarn install multiple times but not use!

Thanks in advance.